# Getting error when try to create SQL Server database on server

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, hosting, plesk

I am trying to create a SQL Server database on server but it's not getting created when I try to create MySQL database it gets successfully created but m getting following error when I try to create SQL Server database please guys help me it has wasted my 5 days and I am already running late on this project

Please guys comment if you know anything related to this

[I am getting following error please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h82sK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible causes:

1. SQL Server is not installed.
2. The SQL Server Authentication mode is only enabled for Windows Authentication mode
3. An incorrect hostname/instance name is used for SQL Server
4. Plesk installation is corrupted

**Resolutions**

1. Install SQL Server if it is not installed:

   ```
   "%plesk_bin%\\ai.exe" --select-product-id panel --select-release-current --show-components

   mssql2008 [up2date] - SQL Server 2008 
   mssql2008-only [up2date] - SQL Server 2008 only
   mssql2012 [install] - SQL Server 2012 
   mssql2012-only [install] - SQL Server 2012 only

   "%plesk_bin%\\ai.exe" --select-product-id panel --select-release-current --install-component mssql2008-only
   ```
2. Enable "SQL server and Windows Authentication Mode" and retry SQL Server registration in `Plesk`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx
3. Make sure the connection to SQL Server using the same host name, user and password that specified in Plesk ->Tools and Settings->Database Servers is possible. Check this using SQL Server Management Studio or other SQL Server database manager
4. Run `"%plesk_bin%"\reconfigurator.exe` with chosen Repair `Plesk` Installation option.

Comment: the problem was i have not installed SQl Sever

Comment: now i have installed it but there is new error mssqlmng failed: Login failed for user 'abelltec'.

Comment: >>>there is new error mssqlmng failed: Login failed for user 'abelltec'<<< Go to sql server error log to find out the reason